# Unique representation of 2 or more arrays

Tags: algorithm

I have got several arrays of fixed length where each component can take on natural number values. In my program 2 vectors are identical in this simple case
0001112
1110002

2220001 would also be identical to these 2 arrays

My question is how can I get a unique representation for these two arrays?

Cheers

Comment: In what sense are they "identical" (*equivalent* may be a better term)? The same set of elements occurs in each?

Comment: They're "identical" because they share some given pattern?  That is, `0001112` is identical to `1110002` and `2220001` because they all share the form: `aaabbbc`?

Comment: if you got your answer then you should mark it as answer. That's the way this site works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how your equivalence relation is defined, but building a set representation out of the arrays satisfies the constraint you've given. There are two ways of doing this:

1. Convert to an appropriate data structure (sets are built-in in many languages, otherwise a hash table or BST will do).
2. Sort each array, remove the duplicate elements and truncate them. Since they're fixed-length, you'll have to store the number of distinct elements somewhere, or use -1 to signal "end of elements".

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store them in a dictionary (hash table) mapping each number to the number of times it appears. Your two arrays would have the same representation:

```
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<int> GetUniqueRepresentation(int[] array)
{
    int count = 1;
    var output = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < array.Length && array[i] == array[i - 1])
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            output.Add(count);
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```